# How to export query results from Postgres to a CSV file

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.3, pgadmin

I am a beginner with Postgres and am trying to figure out how to export my data output (results) onto Excel or a CSV file. I was able to export my results onto a CSV file, but the results are not exactly what I received in my "Data Output" pane. Is there a way to have exactly what I am seeing in my Postgres Output Pane - Data Output in a CSV or Excel file?

Please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The copy command is the best way to do this:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-copy.html

> COPY table_name [ ( column_name [, ...] ) ]
>       FROM { 'filename' | PROGRAM 'command' | STDIN }
>       [ [ WITH ] ( option [, ...] ) ]
>
> COPY { table_name [ ( column_name [, ...] ) ] | ( query ) }
>       TO { 'filename' | PROGRAM 'command' | STDOUT }
>       [ [ WITH ] ( option [, ...] ) ]
>
> where option can be one of:
>
> ```
> FORMAT format_name
> OIDS [ boolean ]
> FREEZE [ boolean ]
> DELIMITER 'delimiter_character'
> NULL 'null_string'
> HEADER [ boolean ]
> QUOTE 'quote_character'
> ESCAPE 'escape_character'
> FORCE_QUOTE { ( column_name [, ...] ) | * }
> FORCE_NOT_NULL ( column_name [, ...] )
> ENCODING 'encoding_name'
> ```